# How would you configure Brutile to use Macrostrat.org as a tile server

Tags: c#

I am wanting to create a active tile layer in a C#, WPF application that uses Mapsui and Brutile.  Using Brutile, can geology map available MacroStrat.org be used as a map tile source?

[**Macrostrat.org** - With over 225 maps from data providers around the world across every scale, Macrostrat is the world's largest homogenized geologic map database](https://macrostrat.org/)

[**Brutile** - BruTile is a .NET Standard 1.1 library to access tile services like OpenStreetMap and Bing](https://github.com/BruTile/BruTile)

[**Mapsui** -  Mapsui is a C# map component for apps. Supported platforms: Xamarin.Forms (including Android, iOS, MacOS, UWP and WPF)](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with using this Reddit forum which the author provided the proper url for Macrostrat.

[Partial answer found at Reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/ou775z/connect_qgis_to_macrostrat_dot_org/) - Giving credit where credit is due.

Macrostrat.org uses Open Street Map as a base, so I assumed the setup in Brutile in for Macrostrat could be modelled after the KnownTileSource for OpenStreet Map.

Steps:

1. Using GitHub, I created my own fork of Brutile.
2. Edited file:  ..\BruTile/Predefined/KnownTileSources.cs
3. Added new value of Macrostrat to  public enum KnownTileSource.
4. Added new method to public static class KnownTileSources

   private static readonly Attribution MacrostratAttribution = new Attribution(
   "© Macrostrat contributors", "https://macrostrat.org/#about");
5. Modified existing method: public static HttpTileSource Create(...)
6. Added the following case to the top of the switch statement:

   public static HttpTileSource Create(KnownTileSource source = KnownTileSource.OpenStreetMap, string apiKey = null,
   IPersistentCache<byte[]> persistentCache = null, Func<Uri, byte[]> tileFetcher = null, string userAgent = null)
   {
   switch (source)
   {
   case KnownTileSource.Macrostrat:
   return new HttpTileSource(new GlobalSphericalMercator(0, 18),
   "https://tiles.macrostrat.org/carto/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
   new[] { "a", "b", "c" }, name: source.ToString(),
   persistentCache: persistentCache, tileFetcher: tileFetcher,
   attribution: MacrostratAttribution, userAgent: userAgent);

(Code unified diff using TortoiseGit)

[image]

Comment: Can someone with privledge create the following tags for me:  Brutile  ,Mapsui, and Macrostrat.  thx